# Isolated dc dc converter

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, isolation, transceiver, isolated

What is the best way (low cost) to obtain a 5v isolated output from 24v batt? The 5v isolated is only for power transceivers so not to much current output is required

[image]

Comment: How are you isolating the data on the power transceiver? Show your schematic please.

Comment: I uploaded the application I want to use

Comment: I linked a document in my answer that recommends using the SN6501 with the ISO1042 you are using. The data sheet for the 6501 gives a full and decent list of various transformers you can use on [page 21](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn6501.pdf?ts=1609255123757&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FSN6501).

Comment: Yes I read.. thanks for the answers. I only provided you the sch FYI .. by the way I have an other question: if I have 2 transceiver I must provide two isolations? One for transceiver or 1 isolation is enough? Sorry for my noobies questions

Comment: One might be enough but two are going to be more resilient to ground loops or other forms of EMI.

Comment: Thanks for the useful advices

Answer (score 3):

I'd consider using this type of set-up: -

[image]

They are used (as recommended by TI) in this type of application: -

[image]

But will serve equally well in straightforward data applications such as RS485 or isolated SPI buses (as indicated in the data sheet extract above).

And for CAN bus, [TI recommend using the SN6501 with the ISO1042](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla334a/slla334a.pdf?ts=1609284894017): -

[image]